# Using Doubleclick Bid Manager API

Tags: double-click-advertising

I am writing a Python program to read line items from Doubleclick Bid Manager using its API, but facing issue while making a query to getlineitems.
To Authenticate, here is my code:

```
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
# After entering the verification for code,
code = raw_input('Code: ').strip()
credential = flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

I successfully get my credential as a oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials object.
Then using following parameters, I make a http request.

```
params = dict(
    api_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' # client secret from the API JSON file
)

url = 'https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems'

r = requests.get(url = url, params=params)
```

But my request returns 404; not found code. Per the API guidelines (https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems), you need to make following HTTP request.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about python, but since the call is a POST request, should you be using requests.get()? Is there a request.post() method?